# Collapse nested accordion groups based on custom class

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 with Asp.net MVC.

I have a set of nested accordions on a tab pane and other accordions on other tab panes.

The External accordions are in an accordion-group and the Internal accordions are in another group, nested inside each External accordion.

[image: Accordions]

The colours are applied using CSS rules on custom classes.

```
.accordion-toggle.outcome {
    background-color:#d9edf7;
}

.accordion-toggle.outcome.collapsed {
    background-color:White;
}

.accordion-toggle.achievement {
    background-color:#dff0d8;
}

.accordion-toggle.achievement.collapsed {
    background-color:White;
}
```

I need to force the full collapse of the open accordions depending on which new accordion is selected. If an internal accordion is selected then I only want the other internal accordions to close. If an external accordion is selected I want the internal and external accordions to close.

Closing means assigning the '`collapsed`' class to the `accordion-toggle`, which determines the highlight colour of the `accordion-heading`.

I have the following javascript which needs amending to select the different levels of accordion. The class of '`outcome`' for External and '`achievement`' for internal are currently the only difference between the two.

I've tried a variety of if/else combinations but none of them seem to work. I've included the javascript I use when changing tabs as this might change how I need to approach this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //need to collapse all when tab changes
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {            
        $('.accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').addClass('collapsed');
        $('.accordion').find('.accordion-body').removeClass('in');
        $('.accordion').find('.accordion-body').height('0px');                    
        }
         );

    //collapse accordion depending on class
    // from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7213#issuecomment-18547519
    $('.collapse').on('hide', function () {

        //do something to select internal or external accordion here...

                $('[href="#' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').addClass('collapsed');

        });

</script>
```

The HTML for the above accordion set is as follows:

```
<div class="accordion" id="interventions">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle outcome collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#interventions" href="#collapse12">
        <label for="">Test Finance</label>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse12" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion" id="intervention0">
        <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle achievement" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#intervention0" href="#collapse012">
              <label for="">Achievement Finance 3</label>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse012" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
              <div class="accordion-group">Test group</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle achievement" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#intervention0" href="#collapse111">
              <label for="">Achievement Finance 2</label>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse111" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
              <div class="accordion-group">Test group</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle outcome collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#interventions" href="#collapse10">
        <label for="">Huge Money</label>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse10" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion" id="intervention1">
        <div class="accordion-group">
          <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle achievement" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#intervention1" href="#collapse010">
              <label for="">Achievement Finance 1</label>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse010" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
              <div class="accordion-group">Test group</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort this out using the following javascript. The custom classes are only used by the CSS to apply the correct colour to an `accordion-toggle` when it is open or collapsed.

The css is amended to:

```
.accordion-toggle.outcome {
    background-color:#d9edf7;
}

.accordion-toggle.achievement {
    background-color:#dff0d8;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Thanks to Ammu for helping with [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974988).

### Javascript

```
//function to collapse all accordions when changing tabs
function tabCollapse() {
    $('.accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').addClass('collapsed');        
    $('.accordion').find('.accordion-body').removeClass('in');
    $('.accordion').find('.accordion-body').height('0px');
}

//function to fully collapse accordion on same page
function pageCollapse(inner) {
    $('#' + inner).find('.accordion-toggle').addClass('collapsed');        
    $('#' + inner).find('.accordion-body').removeClass('in');
    $('#' + inner).find('.accordion-body').height('0px');
}

//collapse all when tab changes
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function () {
    tabCollapse();
});

//collapse inner accordion on same page
$('.accordion').on('hidden', function (e) {        
    var inner = e.target.id;
    pageCollapse(inner);
});

//on hide remove colour
$('.accordion').on('hide', function (e) {
    var selected = e.target.id;
    $('#' + selected).siblings().find('.accordion-toggle').addClass('collapsed');
});
```